# Keep alive app after killing from background

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my VOIP app when my app is in background any incoming call notify my app and everything is fine. But when my app is killed from background incoming call can not notify me.

I used `setKeepAliveTimeout:handler` but I came to know that it only works when app is in background.

How can I do the similar when the app is killed from background that is incoming call will notify the app when the app is killed from background.

Comment: You should use `pushKit` to send a push notification to your app.  A PushKit push will re-launch your app if it is killed

Comment: I used `pushKit` and it is working when my app is in background but not when app is killed from background.

Comment: According to the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/EnergyGuide-iOS/OptimizeVoIP.html) a PushKit push should relaunch your application if it is not running, however, this may only be if iOS has terminated the app.  In many cases if the user terminates an app from the app switcher then it will stay terminated until the user launches it again, on the assumption that the user did not want that app running.  Perhaps you could send a regular push with a message if your app doesn't respond to the pushkit push

Comment: Then what you say, if I terminate the app from background then it will not receive any incoming call notification if I use `pushKit` is it? Please clear this.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't offer any further clarification as I have never tried it.  All I can go on is the documentation; if you are finding that PushKit doesn't notify a user-terminated app then that is the case; I assume that your app has "Voice Over IP" selected in background modes